# JavaScript combining function parameter with excisting variable

Tags: javascript, variables, parameters

I am creating a piece of code that repeats for multiple variables and I was wondering if it might be easier to make a function for it, and in the function 'dynamically' adjust the variable that I need to change.

Example: I am creating 31 doors that are either open or closed. So I have:

```
var door1State = 0;
var door2State = 0;
...
var door31State = 0;
```

My question is wether it's possible to create a function where I pass the door number as a parameter, like this:

```
function openDoor(doorNumber) {
   door+doorNumber+State = 1;
}
```

So when I bind a listener to the door, I don't have to write anonymous functions everytime.

I hope my explanation is clear, if not I'm happy to clarify it a bit more.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Thanks for all the helpfull replies, I have a next question regarding this issue. I am working with 'Blippar', and they have an API which works fairly easy, but now I need to animate the doors to open. First I've declared the 'sprites' in the 'scene', and next I need to animate the specific parts

```
deur1.onTouchEnd = function() {
if (door1Openable == 1) {
  deur1.animate().rotationY(180).scale(600,360).translation(0,0,95).duration(1000);
  deur1text.animate().rotationY(0).scale(600,360).translation(0,0,100).duration(1000);

  setTimeout(function(){
    door1State = 1;
  }, 1500);
} else {
  return false;
}
```

This happens 31 times, for 31 doors. My question is, how would it be easiest to covert this into a function with parameters? The only required parameters are 'door number', 'x position' and 'y position'.

I tried something like this, which obviously didn't work, but I'm having a hard time finding the correct way to do it.

```
function() openDoor(doorNumber,xPos,yPos) {
if ('door'+doorNumber+'Openable' == 1) {
  'deur'+doorNumber.animate().rotationY(180).scale(600,360).translation(xPos,yPos,95).duration(1000);
  'deur'+doorNumber+'text'.animate().rotationY(0).scale(600,360).translation(xPos,yPos,100).duration(1000);

  setTimeout(function(){
    'door'+doorNumber+'Openable' = 1;
  }, 1500);
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Again, hopefully it's clear enough, I am basically trying to dynamically use variables within a function by using parameters.

EDIT 2: The API doesn't accept window[] for some reason, it runs in-app.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an array that holds your state

```js
const Doors=[
{
  id:1,
  isOpen:true,
},
{
  id:2,
  isOpen:true,
},
{
  id:3,
  isOpen:false,
}
//..etc
]
```

this is much easier to handle and manipulate than a huge number of variables.

To open the door you can do something like this :

```js
const OpenDoor=(doorNumber)=>{
Doors.forEach(function(door, index) {
  if(door.id===doorNumber)
    Doors[index].isOpen = true;  
});
}
```

and then `OpenDoor(3);`

Comment: Thanks, would you also have an answer for my edit? It must be in ES5 tho, since the API doesn't accept ES6.

Comment: it's better to close this one and open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, if you change the `door#State` variables to a *single object* instead of 31 separate variables. Then, you can just use bracket notation to look up the correct object.:

```
const doorStates = { door1State: 0, door2State: 0, ... };
function openDoor(doorNumber) {
  doorStates['door' + doorNumber + 'state'] = 1;
}
```

Or, you might consider using an array instead:

```
// Create an array of length 31, all elements are 0:
const doorStates = Array.from({ length: 31 }, () => 0);

function openDoor(doorNumber) {
  // arrays are zero-indexed
  doorStates[doorNumber - 1] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make a dictionary of the doors.
It seems like your usage might merit the use of a dictionary instead of multiple variables.
Here's an example:

```
list_dict = {};
function(doorname)
{
    this.list_dict[doorname] = 0;
}
```

You might also want to read a bit about maps, here: [Javascript Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

```
function openDoor(number) {
  window['door'+number+'State'] = 1;
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
  window['door'+i+'State'] = 0;
}

openDoor(2)
console.log(door2State)
```

You can also use an array for that:

```
var doors = [
   0,0,0,0,0,0,...0 // to 31 0s
];
```

Then reference door1State using doors[0]

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use window[] in this API